# Usar Filezilla desde la linea de comandos de Windows

Tags: cmd, ftp, filezilla

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de subir un archivo comprimido a un directorio **ftp** a través de la linea de comandos. 
He conseguido acceder a **filezilla** y situarme en el directorio donde se encuentra el contenido a subir, pero no he logrado localizar cual es la opción que realiza la subida al **ftp.**

Adjunto el fragmento que realiza esto:

> cd C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client filezilla
>   [ftp://direccion@contraseña](ftp://direccion@contrase%C3%B1a) --local C:\Ruta local\ exit

Agradezco mucho la ayuda por adelantado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

*Traducción de la mejor [respuesta](https://superuser.com/questions/239860/how-do-i-send-a-file-with-filezilla-from-the-command-line) en superuser.com*

Fillezilla no cuenta con parámetros para carga de archivos por línea de comandos:

[Fillezilla Command line arguments (Client)](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))

Puedes usar otro cliente FTP que permita automatización como WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

Un script típico para subir archivos es el siguiente (script.txt):

```
open ftp://user:password@example.com/
put c:\files\*.* /home/user/
exit
```

Para ejecutar el script:

```
WinSCP.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /script=script.txt
```

WinSCP 5.9 y superior puede [generar un script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl) de una [sesión importada de FileZilla](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

Para detalles ver la [guía de automatización de Filezilla](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_filezilla_automation)